# MongoDB updateMany with dynamic filter

Tags: mongodb, filter, dynamic, realm

How can I use UpdateMany with dynamic filters in the MongoDB Realm Node.js SDK?

I have an array of objects and I want to update/insert each object in the database using UpdateMany with dynamic filters. Here's an example of the data:

```
const docs = [
   { id: '1', name: 'John Doe', age: 30 },
   { id: '2', name: 'Jane Doe 2', age: 25 },
   { id: '3', name: 'Bob Smith', age: 35 },
   { id: '4', name: 'Bob gm 2', age: 20 },
   { id: '5', name: 'bbbbb', age: 21 },
]
```

I want to use the id field of each object in the docs array as the filter to update or insert the object. The MongoDB Realm Node.js SDK doesn't support bulk operations, so I'm looking for an alternative way to achieve this.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
const filter = { id: { $in: docs.map(doc => doc.id) } }
const update = { $set: {} }
const options = { upsert: true } 
const result = await collection.updateMany(filter, update, options)
```

if I pass docs to { $set: docs }, mongodb returns error

> Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead

I have larger dataset so can't use updateone in loop, that is not the option.

Comment: Your `update` does not do anything. Apart from that, your code is fine. What is your problem?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit that is the question actually, if I pass { $set: {docs} } it doesn't work so question is how can I pass objects array in update  with {$set: {}}

Comment: I think this can be done only with Bulk updates or with a loop. [$switch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) would be possible, but I don't think in your case  that's an option either.

Comment: unfortunately, the Realm SDK does not support bulk operations, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: i think its better to use `transaction` with query `update/updateOne`. it will be easier to hande your dinamic filter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this using `updateMany`, but if you want to do it in a single operation. You can create a dummy collection and insert your documents into that collection. After that, use an aggregation pipeline to merge your temporary collection, with the original collection. Like this:

```
const docs = [
   { id: '1', name: 'John Doe', age: 30 },
   { id: '2', name: 'Jane Doe 2', age: 25 },
   { id: '3', name: 'Bob Smith', age: 35 },
   { id: '4', name: 'Bob gm 2', age: 20 },
   { id: '5', name: 'bbbbb', age: 21 },
];
await tempCollection.insertMany(docs);
await tempCollection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $merge: {
          into: "collection",
          on: "_id",
          whenMatched: "replace",
          whenNotMatched: "insert",
      }
    }
  ]
);
await tempCollection.remove({});
```

You can wrap all three queries in a transaction, it's a good thing to do. Also, I am additionally cleaning the `tempCollection` after merging, it's an optional step, use it if you find it useful.